# How to implement a zoom in/out effect on GridView in Android

Tags: android, user-experience, zooming

When creating images and texts it is very common to develop a zoom in/out feature in UI, as it haves many applications mainly related to accessibility. In my situation, I'd like to create a customized type of view similar to a gridview, but with the difference that the data is not scrolled but transpassed in front/back directions, so in my case, it is more related to user-experience than accessibility. In [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x4fr5wX57jg) video the described "behavior" is better resumed/defined. I want to create a gridview with this effect, where the previous items can be bring from the "out-screen" to screen and the next items can be bring from the "deep-screen" to the screen, and the gridview itself is static in relation to scrolls. Is it possible? Currently, I'm taking efforts to create it all from scratch using **onScrollStateChanged** and default zoom implementations through size-scale the data (which is a very harsh solution).
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you find any solution for it ? i also face same problem.